# Import IOS SMS and iMessage Messages in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've been digging around on the internet but haven't found anything close to what I'm looking for. Is there any way to load all SMS and iMessage messages into a custom Xamarin IOS app. I don't want to send or receive messages, just view messages that are already on the phone or tablet.Even if there is a Xamarin Forms solution for accessing existing messages, that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to read SMS messages due to privacy concerns.

you have to Log in to the developers portal and click App Store Review Guidelines.

Nowhere in the guidelines does it specify that you can't access the SMSes. But you can only access then if you use private methods which is not allowed and will get you app rejected.

You can only access data for which Apple supplies a documented API. You can not access file outside of the Sandbox of your App, unless Apple provides an API for it.

Comment: That's extremely helpful. Can you think of any work around to select portions of conversations and then load them into another app?

Comment: There are ways, but it will get your app rejected.

Comment: not possible with official SDK.

you can only check is status is changed. so basically if you receive a notification.

Comment: It may achieve by jailbroken device.

Apple said - In iPhone OS 4.0 and later, you can send text messages from within your application. This feature is strictly for sending messages. Incoming SMS messages go to the built-in Messages app.